# How to convert document.title in hyper link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

```
<a 
    href="javascript:void(0);" 
    onclick="window.location.href='http://goo.gl';">My link</a>
```

I need to replace My link with Javascript to `document.title`

Comment: this is urgent please help me out My link convert into current page title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<a 
    href="javascript:void(0);" 
    onclick="window.location.href='http://goo.gl';">    
    <script>
        document.write(document.title);
    </script>
</a>
```

Comment: in anchor link format like shows in q thank

Comment: can you limit the no of characters in document.title

Comment: This will only show 10 characters : `document.write(document.title.substr(0,10));`

Comment: superb Thanks now i going to search how to hide words from document.title. like Link,books,templates

Comment: yikes. what on earth is that?